# What does the "Body tag" field do in JSFiddle.net

Tags: jsfiddle

I'm trying to understand what the Body tag field does in JSFiddle and it is not referenced in their docs (that I could find). I ask because I'd like to control the CSS of the body and html tags, possibly without style tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Body Tag:
One can change the body tag. It is usually done to change the styling as `<body class="dark_ui">`. Some frameworks (Dojo) are using it to style the widgets and load CSS

http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

The docs aren't super clear, but it turns out you enter the full opening body tag here, angle brackets and all. For example to get an Angular app to wrap the entire page you'd use:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

In the Body Tag field under Fiddle Options.

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/uwgun40e/